# Best control to handle changin images and text in a asp.net button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a asp.net website.. and I need a little help.. please see image as reference...[image]

What I want to happen is when a button is click from the buttons on the right.. text would appear on the boxed space... I don't know which is the best control to use to hold the text on the space I would like text to appear..

which is the best control to hold images and texts at the same time? and how could I connect it to the button on the right?

Comment: Wouldn't those just be links to pages of different content?

Comment: yes that's what I would like o happen kinda like the master page but the button on the right would just appear in a specific content page so I can't really place them as part of the master page...

Comment: It's still not clear what you're looking for.  Are you just looking to duplicate a menu of links on a subset of pages?  You could put it on the master page and display it conditionally, have a second master page for the pages which have the menu, make a user control of the menu and add that to the content pages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the HtmlGenericControl class. It has a constructor which accepts a string variable which initializes a new instance of the HtmlGenericControl class with the specified tag:

var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

It is also has InnerHtml and InnerText properties.

Setting up a div with the custom content means you could host images, text or basically anything else that you want to stuff inside a div.